# combine two lists into a dictionary if a pattern matches

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have  basically a list of all the files in a folder, which in a simplified version looks like :

```
file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']
```

Another list :

```
drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']
```

I want to combine these two list into a dictionary, such that:

```
dictionary = {
    '17A' : ['drug.resp1.17A.tag' , 'drug.resp2.17A.tag' ], 
    '96A' : ['drug.resp1.96A.tag' , 'drug.resp2.96A.tag' ], 
    '56B' : ['drug.resp1.56B.tag' , 'drug.resp2.56B.tag' ]}
```

I thought of doing like this but got stuck !

```
dict_drugs = {}
for file in file_list:
    list_filename = file.split('.')
    for elem in drug_list:
        if elem in list_filename:
```

What can I do after this to join the elements into a dictionary, or am I doing this completely wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you don't need inner loop

```
>>> file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']
>>> dictonary = {}
... for i in file_list:
...     k = i.split('.')[-2]
...     if k in dictonary:
...         dictonary[k].append(i)
...     else:
...         dictonary[k] = [i]
>>> dictonary
62: {'17A': ['drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag'],
 '56B': ['drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag'],
 '96A': ['drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']}
>>>
```

---

one more check if only needs those values that are present in drug_list

means if file_list contains :

file_list = [ '**drug.resp1.18A.tag**', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']

```
>>> drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']
... dictonary = {}
... for i in file_list:
...     k = i.split('.')[-2]
...     if k in drug_list:
...         if k in dictonary:
...             dictonary[k].append(i)
...         else:
...             dictonary[k] = [i]
>>>
```

**One more way to efficently do upper case:**

```
dictonary = dict(((i,[]) for i in drug_list))

dictonary = {drug: [] for drug in drug_list}  # As @J.F. Sebastian suggested.

for file in file_list:
    k = file.split('.')[-2]
    if k in dictonary:
        dictonary[k].append(file)
```

Comment: `well please leave a comment if you down vote, bcoz the answer is correct and efficient with respect to the question`

Comment: I'll counter +1 - looks good to me. You could even use a `defaultdict` to slice off a few more lines :)

Comment: +1 for the last snippet. You could use `d = {drug: [] for drug in drug_list}`. `k`, `i` are bad names for a drug and a filename correspondingly.

Comment: You'll need to rewrite your algorithm if the naming convention is changed. The question doesn't even specify that the location of drug ID is constant. Though it seems your answer is correct since it's accepted.

Comment: Hi, tcb I think that doesn't affect it. And I don't understand the meaning of `the location of drug ID is constant`.

Comment: Will your algorithm work if there is a file with name `drug.96A.resp1.tag`?

Comment: Definately not. but still it won't break. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all the files have a corresponding match in the drug list:

```
dic = {d:[] for d in drug_list}
for file in file_list: dic[file.split('.')[-2]].append(file)
```

Comment: +1. I don't really understand why the others come up with so complicated answers for such a simple problem (given the data is strongly regular as seen in the question).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `itertools` and `groupby` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for more information), the goal of which is to provide a `key` value that you use to 'group' your `file_list` (note that the `sorted` piece is necessary because the items need to be in sorted order to group properly):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']

In [3]: drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']

In [4]: grouper = lambda x: x.split('.')[-2]

In [5]: d = {}

In [6]: for key, group in groupby(sorted(file_list, key=grouper), key=grouper):
   ...:     d[key] = list(group)
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [7]: d
Out[7]: 
{'17A': ['drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag'],
 '56B': ['drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag'],
 '96A': ['drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']}
```

What this does is group each item in your `file_list` by the second-to-last element after you split, and then assign the resulting group to the key found at that location. The `grouper` part is to save a little space - since we will be sorting the list by our special key and then grouping by that same key using the `lambda` function, we just store that function in a separate variable so that the `groupby` clause is a bit easier to read.

One thing to note is that this doesn't depend on your `drug_list`, which may or may not be important to you. For instance, this would group something like `drug.resp1.1000A.tag` into the `1000A` group.

As mentioned by @J.F.Sebastian, you can efficiently include only those drugs found in your `drug_list` by converting the list to a `set`, which will include only unique items and has the benefit of having O(1) lookups (meaning that saying `if a in b` does not need to search through the entire object, as is the case with lists):

```
In [10]: drug_list = set(drug_list)

In [11]: only_listed = (f for f in file_list if grouper(f) in drug_list)

In [12]: only_listed
Out[12]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x24fcbe0>

In [13]: for key, group in groupby(sorted(only_listed, key=grouper), key=grouper):
   ....:     d[key] = list(group)
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [14]: d
Out[14]: 
{'17A': ['drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag'],
 '56B': ['drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag'],
 '96A': ['drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']}
```

Comment: to filter according to `drug_set = set(drug_list)`, you could add `if key in drug_set: d[key] = ...` or before sorting: `(f for f in file_list if grouper(f) in drug_set)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Great call as always (I was trying to avoid the O(n) list lookups - `set` escaped my mind :) ). I'll amend to reflect.

Comment: Very interesting and extensive answer but it's like breaking a fly on the wheel. Keep it simple. :)

Comment: @PeterStahl Ha, never heard that expression, I like it :) Agree that if the real data is the same as above then a simple list comprehension is the way to do, but I think the others and I were aiming for a solution that would encompass as many different types of data as possible so that adjustments wouldn't need to be made when the files/drugs expand to include significantly more.

Comment: @RocketDonkey Yeah, I thought that this was your intention. Thumbs up for that. :) But I also had to laugh a bit that nearly everyone was thinking in a so complicated way that nobody came up with the most simple and straightforward answer. But diversity is always good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict_drugs = {s:[] for s in drug_list}

for file in file_list:
    list_filename = file.split('.')
    for elem in list_filename:
        if elem in drug_list:
            dict_drugs[elem].append(file)
```

I changed the order of checks, so it searches for a part of filename in the dictionary rather than a drug in a filename.

Also, note that dictionary was initialized in the beginning with an empty list for every drug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 comprehensions to naturally loop over the data structures.

```
dict((drug, [file for file in file_list if drug in file]) for drug in drug_list)
```

Let's break this down. We'll need to create a dictionary, so let's use a list comprehension for that.

```
dict((a, str(a + " is the value")) for a in [1, 2, 3])
```

The outermost part is a list comprehension that creates a dict. By creating 2-tuples of the form (key, value) we can then simply call dict() on it to get a dictionary. In our answer, we set the drug as the key and we set the value to a list that is built from another list comprehension. So far we have:

```
{'17A': [SOMETHING],
 '56B': [SOMETHING],
 '96A': [SOMETHING]}
```

Now we need to fill in the SOMETHINGs and this is what the inner comprehension does. It looks like your logic is to check if the drug text appears in the file. We already have the drug, so we can just say:

```
[file for file in file_list if drug in file]
```

This runs through the file list and adds it if the drug appears therein.

In Python 2.7 and above, you can use a dictionary comprehension instead of using dict(). In that case it would look like:

```
{drug: [file for file in file_list if drug in file] for drug in drug_list}
```

This is much clearer since all the boiler plate of making 2-tuples and converting can be done away with.

Comprehensions are an excellent way of writing code because the tend to be very clear descriptions of what you mean to do. It's worth noting that this is not the most efficient way of building the dictionary though, since it runs through every file for every drug. If the list of files is very long this could be very slow.

*Edit: My first answer was nonsense. As penance, I have made this detailed one.*

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.ifilter` can make this into a single line dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter
>>> file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']
>>> drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']
>>> { k: list( ifilter( lambda v: k in v, file_list ) ) for k in drug_list }
{
    '56B': ['drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag'], 
    '96A': ['drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag'], 
    '17A': ['drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings in your drug list are always substrings of the strings in your file list, you can do it with three simple code lines.

```
In [1]: d = {}

In [2]: for drug in drug_list:
  ....:     d[drug] = [file for file in file_list if drug in file]

In [3]: d
Out[3]: 
{'17A': ['drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag'],
 '56B': ['drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag'],
 '96A': ['drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']}
```

Comment: If the dataset is exactly as listed above, definitely the cleanest way - I think the only issue is if you have a file like `drug.resp1.17A.tag` and another like `drug.resp1.117A.tag`, both of which would get grouped with `17A`. However if that isn't the case, this is a non-issue :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey True, but I always write my answers strictly according to what is provided in the question. Of course, it doesn't necessarily have to be the best approach for this problem. But usually I favor the *keep it as simple as possible* way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep the problem as simple as possible :

```
file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag',      'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']
drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']
result = {}

for drug in drug_list:
   result[drug] = []
   for file_name in file_list:
       if drug in file_name:
           result[drug].append(file_name)
```

Comment: There is certainly an uber cool way to do this with a list comprehension but thos tricks can easily mess with your mind :)

Comment: Look at my answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Indeed, your solution is definitely more pythonic. Nice one !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
import re

file_list = [ 'drug.resp1.17A.tag', 'drug.resp1.96A.tag', 'drug.resp1.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.17A.tag', 'drug.resp2.56B.tag', 'drug.resp2.96A.tag']
drug_list = [ '17A', '96A', '56B']
drugIdRegex = re.compile(r"drug\.resp\d+\.(?P<drugId>\d+\w+)\.tag")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = dict.fromkeys(drug_list, None)
    for file_name in file_list:
        matcher = drugIdRegex.match(file_name)
        if matcher and matcher.group("drugId") in results:
            if results[matcher.group("drugId")] is None:
                results[matcher.group("drugId")] = list()
            results[matcher.group("drugId")].append(file_name)
    print "Results: %s" % results
```

Although I'm pretty sure you can do it with list comprehensions in one line!! That'd be cool (but I don't know how) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2


   {i:[v for v in file_list if i in v] for i in drug_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that you don't know the numbers of drugs, and there may be new drugs coming in the future.

I really like Faruk's answer, pretty much my way of thinking, but I would add it the drug_list creation.

```
drug_list = list(set([x.split('.')[-2] for x in file_list]))
```